# Editable label in Python GTK+ 3?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, pygtk

I'm new to GTK programming. I want to have a Label widget whose text can be edited, kind of like this: https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.EditableLabel.html.

The problem is I have no idea how to implement this. I understand that `Gtk.Button` has a `set_label()` function, though I don't know how to use it to make an editable label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with [Gtk.Entry](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Entry.html#Gtk.Entry) which you can `set_editable` based on "something". Example with check button would look something like this:

```python
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk


def on_editable_toggled(button, entry):
    value = button.get_active()
    entry.set_editable(value)
    entry.set_sensitive(value)
    

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

vbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=6)
win.add(vbox)

entry = Gtk.Entry()
entry.set_text("Hello World")

vbox.pack_start(entry, True, True, 0)

check_editable = Gtk.CheckButton(label="Editable")
check_editable.connect("toggled", on_editable_toggled, entry)
check_editable.set_active(True)

vbox.pack_start(check_editable, True, True, 0)

win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

It doesn't really look like a label, but you can use the [Gtk CSS styling](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/css-overview.html) to change the background and border colors to make it look like one when it is set to non-editable.